# The best approach of using ReactJS with Sitecore 8.2

Tags: reactjs, sitecore, sitecore-habitat

I am new to ReactJS and Right now working with Sitecore 8.2. In my current project, I have to use ReactJS with Sitecore.

Please suggest what would be the best approach to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach with the most benefits for ReactJS development would be to upgrade to a newer version of Sitecore and use JSS. That will get you the most functionality (https://jss.sitecore.com)

There are some community members who have done ReactJS with older versions of Sitecore: https://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2016/07/23/Sitecore-and-React-It-IS-that-easy/

This even led to the module for Sitecore.React: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/SitecoreReact.aspx

This may get you to where you need for Sitecore 8.2

**UPDATE:** I just recalled that 8.2 also has the SXA JSON Device output that can be used similar to the LayoutService that is used by JSS. You can consume an entire page output as JSON and then consume that on your front-end.

You won't have the helpers that come with JSS, but for headless development with personalization it might be a middle ground.

**Video overview of various headless options:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RiUNvXHzJQ&list=PL1jJVFm_lGnwZup4L4BjITS2sKr4rpMfI&index=1

Comment: Thanks Jay for this information. The last 2 links I have been through and looks like it is tightly coupled. If we go with Sitecore 8.2, do we have any other approach where an entire page could be rendered by using ReactJS only, not involving back-end efforts?

Comment: That's why I suggested JSS. It does exactly what you are looking to do. It wraps around the LayoutService to pull all the data.

However, I just remembered that 8.2 has the SXA JSON device, that might help.